# better params for a conversion to png with imagemagick

Tags: png, imagemagick

i have to convert 60px X 60px images to png for my web site with imagemagick.
convert image.jpg image.png
But it's return an image with 4kbyte size.
I want get a size around 1kbyte.

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compression level is controlled by the `-quality` parameter, look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) for more information. If you are only having images with less than 256 colors, use `-format PNG8` to save some bytes. And try to add `-type optimize`.